Android edge-to-edge and Toolbar height when menu icons are hidden
Since in Android API 35+ the Edge-to-edge behavior is enforced, I'm trying to implement it in my app Toolbar.
This is my current implementation:
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     android:elevation="4dp" />

To apply the top padding:
final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

toolbar.setElevation(0);
toolbar.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.summary));

....

ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(toolbar, (v, windowInsets) -> {
        final Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.displayCutout());
        v.setPadding(paddingLeft + insets.left, paddingTop + insets.top, paddingRight + insets.right, paddingBottom);
        
        // return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
        return ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, windowInsets);
    });

This is what I get: (Partially wrong since the items are not in line)

However, when I hide the menu button, the problem is far more evident:

